# How do you create Facebook share links with custom parameters (header / description) with their new 2.10 API?

Tags: php, facebook, share, facebook-social-plugins

I am looking to mimic what the Skimm does for their newsletter, which allows users to share individual stories from the same webpage to Facebook, and each share link has a unique header and description. (http://theskimm.com/recent)

With Facebook's new API update, you can no longer pass in parameters for image, description, header, etc. Now it just pulls from the og meta tags- however the Skimm clearly found a workaround.

I can not figure it out at all. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: They are simply sharing different URLs ...

Comment: they are sharing the same URL. there's a different ID being passed into the jumpto function but all that does is tell the js to scroll down to that section. the actual url being passed is the same.

Comment: If `http://theskimm.com/2017/07/19/skimm-for-july-20th-3?jumpto=what-people-are-talking-about` and `http://theskimm.com/2017/07/19/skimm-for-july-20th-3?jumpto=thing-to-know` are the same URL to you ... then that simply means you don't know how URLs work, sorry ... _"but all that does is tell the js to scroll down to that section"_ - nope, what that first and foremost does, is makes those two _different_ URLs. (That some JS function might also do something based on this, is totally irrelevant here.)

Comment: The parameter they are passing is different, so sure you can consider that a different url if you'd like. You still didn't really offer any substantial assistance in how they pass the different og tags. You think based on the parameters they pass in different values?

Comment: You can not consider that _anything but_ different URLs, because that is what they are. And yes, of course they deliver different OG tags based on that parameter ... just put them through the Facebook debug tool, that clearly shows it.

Comment: If you pass both of those URLs through the Facebook debug tool, they both have the exact same OG tags and display the same thumbnail.

Comment: When the debug tool shows serious warnings like "Parser Mismatched Metadata" (as it does now), that usually means that it refuses to update the cache with that data - so what you're seeing when you share those URLs are likely older versions of the meta data.

Comment: Interesting. as for my initial problem though they still have all these unique links passing back to the same exact page. that page I'm assuming has a single OG tag for description / title / etc. do you have any idea how to accomplish this? do they swap OG tags on click if that's even possible? is their javascript doing something unique?

Comment: No, you can not switch them via JS, the Facebook scraper does not care about that at all. Since they recently removed all ways to specify this data dynamically at the time of sharing, unique OG meta tags are currently the only way to achieve this. So each unique combination of content attributes needs a unique URL as well. The obvious drawback is that like and share counts will be split across those URLs, too.

Comment: Appreciate the help. It's a shame Facebook changed their API to disable customization. I don't really care much about the like and share counts, it's more about having the ability to display unique thumbnails on Facebook. What's the best way to create a unique url for each, I want them to all load the same page. Or are what you saying is all of those links load a different but identical page?

Comment: Either that, or you have your unique share URLs only deliver the OG meta data to the Facebook scraper, and redirect everyone else to the “real” URL.